# AWS Lambda layer for password protected Excel sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on a requirement to load some password protected excel-sheet from aws workdocs and implement some business logic using aws lambda after that save one csv file in s3 and automate with PowerBI

I have created the python scripts and it is working fine on my machine but when i am trying to upload the zip code on aws the build size is more then 50 mb, so i have decided to create some layers.

I am able to create different layers like pandas, request etc.
When I am trying to create a layer for **msoffcrypto-tool** I am not able to do so, can anyone look into it and suggest me where i am wrong?

Do we have any other library to decrypt the binary excel-sheet that is password protected and extract data for further process.

I have tried some of the library like xlrd, pyexcel but it is not working for me.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path, password=None)

with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    data = pyexcel.get_sheet_by_name(f, sheet_name, password=password)
```

---

I am using the below code it is working fine but not able to run on aws lambda because of **msoffcrypto** dependency.

```
def get_file_content(folder_id, index):
    download_url = get_workdocs(folder_id, index)
    content = get_content(download_url)
    return content

def get_workdocs(folder_id, index):
    """get workdocs"""
    try:
        workdocs = boto3.client(
            WORKDOCS,
            region_name=AWS_REGION,
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        )
        res = workdocs.describe_folder_contents(FolderId=folder_id)
        data = res["Documents"]

        response = workdocs.get_document_version(
            DocumentId=data[index]["Id"],
            VersionId=data[index]["LatestVersionMetadata"]["Id"],
            Fields="SOURCE",
        )
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        return []

    return response["Metadata"]["Source"]["ORIGINAL"]


def get_content(download_url):
    """get folder details."""
    response = requests.get(download_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
        office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
        office_file.load_key(password=FILE_PASSWORD)
        office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)
        # Read the sheet by sheet name using pandas from the decrypted workbook content
        data = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        return data
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download document. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

I have also tried to create layer for  cryptography using wsl, I am getting below error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)",
  "errorType": "ImportError",
  "requestId": "f4cec245-f72c-41c3-877a-d97037000906",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 22, in lambda_handler\n    gt_report = integration.apply_business_rule_on_gt_report_sheet(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/services/integration.py\", line 35, in apply_business_rule_on_gt_report_sheet\n    data = get_data(content, sheet_name)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/services/integration.py\", line 10, in get_data\n    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(io.BytesIO(content))\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/msoffcrypto/__init__.py\", line 53, in OfficeFile\n    from msoffcrypto.format.ooxml import OOXMLFile\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/msoffcrypto/format/ooxml.py\", line 13, in <module>\n    from msoffcrypto.method.ecma376_agile import ECMA376Agile\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/msoffcrypto/method/ecma376_agile.py\", line 9, in <module>\n    from common.cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/common/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py\", line 7, in <module>\n    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives._serialization import (\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py\", line 11, in <module>\n    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import HashAlgorithm\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py\", line 10, in <module>\n    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import openssl as rust_openssl\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: "When I am trying to create a layer for msoffcrypto-tool I am not able to do so, can anyone look into it and suggest me where i am wrong?" How are you doing that? What isn't working? Are there any error messages?